# Mikdash David, Kuntres Tohorot 3:4

Tags: sources-mekorot, jewish-books, mishna, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity

The Artscroll elucidated Mishnah (Oholot 4:1) contains a footnote referring to Mikdash David, Kuntres Tohorot 3:4 (d'h והנה זה). Can anyone help me find a copy of this source?

Comment: https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14790&pgnum=1

Comment: The section on Oholot begins on page 113.

Comment: @YaacovDeane Thanks but I'm struggling to find my way around that - I can't find siman 3:4 and that davar ha-matchil?

Comment: @Gabriel It could be on page 120.

Comment: They were likely using the new edition, edited and footnoted by Rabbi Michoel Elias shlit"a.

Comment: @Zarka it on page 120

Comment: Thanks all; found it thanks to your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14790&pgnum=1 on page 120, thanks to those above